# perfect infinitive for future events

Tags: future, perfect-infinitive

Boss tells his workers:

> **(1)** *You are to **finish** this project by the end of next month*.
>
> **(2)** *You are to **have finished** this project by the end of next month*.

After a while, one of the workers tells his boss:

> **(3)** *You said we were to **finish** this project by the end of next month, but we encountered problems and so can't do it in time*.
>
> **(4)** *You said we were to **have finished** this project by the end of next month, but we encountered problems and so can't do it in time*.

Are (1) & (2) both natural?

Are (3) & (4) both natural?

Hope to hear both Britain and American speakers. Thanks!

Comment: I'd say it's more natural to say ***have*** *this project* ***finished***. But both tenses are fine. Also, it would sound better (to me) if *you are to* were replaced with *you should*.

Comment: Jason Bassford, will it be correct if we replace "_were to_" with "_should_" in (3) & (4)? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that would also work. Or *you said we* ***had to*** …

Comment: I'm still new here but I'm always wondering why such great answers, @Jason Bassford, are kept in the comments. It happens many places. Thank you.

Comment: @Elliot First, I voted to close the question as opinion based. Anybody answering it will just be saying what *they* think is natural—and a list of individual opinions doesn't really belong here. Second, the comments I gave are no more than just saying *these things and others all sound natural*. That *might* work at [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), but not here. That doesn't make a good answer.

Comment: @Jason Bassford As always thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Jason Bassford, will it be correct if we replace "_are to have finished_" in (2) and "_were to have finished_" in (4) with "_ought to have finished_" in them? Thanks!